# Why nogo config is not considered when using bazel coverage

Tags: go, bazel

Hello our golang project is using [nogo](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/nogo.rst) for static code analysis. We also have a nogo-config.json file to exclude certain paths for some of the rules. I found that `bazel build //...` and `bazel test //...` all use the config(because they don't complain the shadow variable error configured in the nogo_config.json) however `bazel coverage //...` will report variable shadow error for code under `foo/bar` which means the `bazel coverage` didn't obey the nogo_config.json. Why?  (I am using bazel 2.2.0, golang go1.13.6 darwin/amd64)

WORKSPACE file

```
go_register_toolchains(nogo = "@//:my_nogo")
```

BUILD.bazel file

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "nogo")
nogo(
    name = "my_nogo",
    config = "nogo-config.json",  # Exclude analysis of 3rd party libraries
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@org_golang_x_tools//go/analysis/passes/shadow:go_tool_library",
    ],
)
```

nogo_config.json

```
{
        "shadow": {
        "exclude_files": {
            "external/*": "",
            "foo/bar/*": "Some generated model files don't behave by these go rules"
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: When a nogo binary is registered, it's used when building any Go library. So `bazel build`, `bazel test`, and `bazel coverage` will all trigger. Could you post more information about the issue you're seeing?

Comment: sorry I will add more details since I found something new. @JayConrod

Comment: @JayConrod I modified the question and whole description after my new findings. sorry for the confusions at the beginning.

Comment: From what you've posted, it's not clear why it would work differently with `bazel coverage` compared with other commands. Is that the actual `nogo_config.json` file? There are syntax errors (mismatched braces), and it uses globs instead of regular expressions to match files. An error should be reported at least for the syntax errors, not sure about the patterns though.